# How to put equation side by side equations?

Tags: color, empheq

My MWE,

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{empheq}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\definecolor{backcolor}{RGB}{255,255,170}
\newcommand*\mybox[1]{%
\colorbox{backcolor}{\hspace{1em}#1\hspace{1em}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{empheq}[box=\mybox]{align}
\alpha \qquad \beta \qquad \gamma
\end{empheq}

\end{document}
```

and displaying

[image]

But, that I want the equations in center, see below the image,

[image]

Is there a basic solution (without multicols and table)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}

\definecolor{backcolor}{RGB}{255,255,170}
\newcommand*\mybox[1]{\colorbox{backcolor}{\hspace{1em}$\strut#1$\hspace{1em}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\mybox{\alpha} \qquad \mybox{\beta} \qquad \mybox{\gamma}
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Would an `equation` environment work just as well as `align` does?

Comment: @Herbert, perfect working with \usepackage{empheq}.